# Combine an echo and a print in one statement

Tags: php, syntax

`echo "1" . (print '2') + 3;` returns 214. How does the script end up with *14?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you do

```
echo "1" . (print '2') + 3;
```

PHP will do ([demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OfrNrs))

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   PRINT                                            ~0      '2'
         1      CONCAT                                           ~1      '1', ~0
         2      ADD                                              ~2      ~1, 3
         3      ECHO                                                     ~2
         4    > RETURN                                                   1
```

In words:

- print 2, return 1
- concat "1" with returned 1 => "11"
- add "11" + 3 => 14
- echo 14

and that's 214.

The operators `+ - .` have equal [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), but are left associative:

> For operators of equal precedence, left associativity means that evaluation proceeds from left to right, and right associativity means the opposite.

---

**Edit:** since all the other answers claim PHP does 1+3, here is further proof that it doesnt:

```
echo "1" . (print '2') + 9;
```

gives 220, e.g. 11+9 and not `1 . (1+9)`. If the addition had precedence over the concatenation, it would have been 2110, but for that you'd had to write

```
echo "1" . ((print '2') + 9);
```

Comment: Thanks! Cool overview btw. Where did you get this?

Comment: @Michiel Click the demo link. The output is on the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "1" . (print '2') + 3;
```

You need to think of it in a logical order, of what happens first.

Before we can echo anything, the - "1" . (print '2') + 3 - we need to evaluate it to solve it.

First we write 1 down on a scrap of paper as the first part of our calculation.

```
Scrap paper: 1
Answer Sheet:
```

We calculate "print '2'", which as a function writes the number 2 to our sheet of answer paper and returns a 1, which we write on our scrap piece of paper.

```
Scrap paper: 1 . 1 +3
Answer Sheet: 2
```

After this we want to concatenate the next piece on to the end, due to the "."

```
Scrap paper: 11 + 3 
Answer Sheet: 2
```

Now we put it together

```
Scrap paper: 11 + 3
Scrap paper: 14
Answer Sheet: 2
```

Then we echo out our scrap data to our answer sheet

Answer Sheet: 214

```
echo "1" . (print '2') + 3;

1.
Code--: echo "1" . (print '2') + 3;
Result: 
2.
Code--: echo "1" . 1 + 3;
Result: 2
3.
Code--: echo 11 + 3;
Result: 2
4.
Code--: echo 14;
Result: 2
5.
Code--: 
Result: 214
```

I hope that makes some sense, and remember the return of print is always 1, and any function that prints or echo's while inside another execution will echo/print before it's caller/parent does.

Answer (score 1):

The 1 in between is actually a `true` statement.
Because `print` statement actually returns a `true`.
So you get 2 (from print), 1 (from echo print), and 4 (from 1+3)

Answer (score -1):

`print` is executed first because of the parenthesis, so it print's `2` first, *[but it returns 1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)*. Then, your echo gets executed, printing `1`. You then concatenate to it the result of `print` (which is 1) with 3 added to it. That's 4.

Answer (score -1):

`print` always return 1 according to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php

So, because arithmetic operator has precedence over one for concatenation, so you get:

`"1" . (1+3)`

... that is "14" ;). And because `print` sends string directly to output you get '2' in front of everything....