# Laravel & Faker gives not a random element of array

Tags: php, laravel, faker

I've a problem with Laravel and Faker. I want to pick a random element out of an array with faker's randomElement function. I have this simple code:

```
$siloID = DB::table('silos')->pluck('id');
echo(print("silos: ".$siloID));
echo(print("\nrandom element: ".$faker->randomElement($siloID)));
```

which is giving me back this on the console:

silos: [3,9,14,18,21,93,42,55,88,99,31,38,65,1,23,68,98,13,39,40,45,49,59,6,11,24,25,60,64,90,94,97,100,4,15,7,26,29,85,35,43,75,22,48,58,80,86,87,62,82,89,30,95,12,28,33,73,17,27,57,72,74,83,91,69,78,37,76,81,20,53,79,32,46,56,77,92,34,41,44,67,16,19,52,61,96,5,10
,47,51,54,84,2,36,66,71,50,70,8,63]1

random element: 851

I don't understand this because 851 is not in the array? What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining `echo` and `print` is creating the issue (its adding a 1 at the end due to the parens).  The `$faker` method `randomElement` **is working correctly**.

**To fix** just remove the extra php method.

```
echo("silos: ".$siloID);
echo("\nrandom element: ".$faker->randomElement($siloID));
```

As I suspect this is just for testing output and your final code won't need the `echo` / `print` statments combined, the `$faker` method should work fine for you.

Comment: thanks! Just out of interest. What makes "print" that this goes wrong?

Comment: It's not really 'wrong', it is just being used in a way that you didn't intend.  You can test by playing around with the variable and adding / removing the print statement inside the echo.  It will sometimes add a `=>1`, which was the clue.  There is an [interesting SO answer on how this processes within PHP here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213885/combine-an-echo-and-a-print-in-one-statement)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to example below. It will return you random array element. here, I'm storing random array value in the JSON format to the database

```
$factory->define(Rule::class, function (Faker $faker) {

    $rule = [
        'age' => [
            'borrower_age_min'  => 'min:21',
            'borrower_age_max'  => 'max:75'
        ],
        'affordability' => [
            'annual_income' => 'integer|min:40000',
            'loan_amount'   => 'integer|max:3*',
        ],
        'finance' => [
            'loan_length'   => 'integer|max:12',
            'loan_amount'   => 'integer|max:500000',
        ]
    ];

    return [
        'rule'     => json_encode([
            $faker->randomElement(
                [
                    $rule['age']['borrower_age_min'],
                    $rule['age']['borrower_age_max'],
                    $rule['affordability']['annual_income'],
                    $rule['affordability']['loan_amount'],
                    $rule['finance']['loan_length'],
                    $rule['finance']['loan_amount']
                ]
            )
        ])
    ];
});
```